# EF Core 7 can't deserialize dynamic-members in JSON column

Tags: json, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I am trying to map my `Name` column to a dynamic object. This is how the raw JSON data looks (*note* that this is SQL-morphed from our old relational data and I am not able to generate or interact with this column via EF Core):

```
{ "en": "Water", "fa": "آب", "ja": "水", ... }
```

Just to note, available languages are stored in a separate table and thus are dynamically defined.

Through T-SQL I can perfectly interact with these objects eg

```
SELECT * 
FROM [MyObjects] 
WHERE JSON_VALUE(Name, '$.' + @languageCode) = @searchQuery
```

But it seems EF Core doesn't want to even deserialize these objects as whole, let alone query them.

What I get in a simple `GetAll` query is an empty `Name`. Other columns are not affected though.

I have tried so far

1. Using an empty class with a `[JsonExtensionData]` dictionary inside
2. Using a `: DynamicObject` inheritance and implementing `GetDynamicMembers`, `TryGetMember`, `TrySetMember`, `TryCreateInstance`
3. Directly mapping to a string dictionary.
4. Combining 1 & 2 and adding an indexer operator on top.

All yield the same results: an empty `Name`.

I have other options like going back to a junction table relational which I have many issues with, hardcoding languages which is not really intuitive and might cause problems in the future, using `HasJsonConversion` which basically destroys the performance on any search action... so I'm basically stuck here with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think currently it's not fully supported:

1. You can not use dynamic operations on an expression tree like a Select statement because it needs to be translated.
2. JsonValue and JsonQuery requires a path to be resolved.
3. If you specify OwnsOne(entity = >entity.owned, owned => owned.ToJson()) and the Json could not be parsed you will get an error.

I suggest this workaround while the EF team improves the functionality.

1. Create a static class with static methods to be used as decoys in the expression tree. This will be mapped to the server built-in functions.

   ```
       public static class DBF
       {
           public static string JsonValue(this string column, [NotParameterized] string path)
           => throw new NotSupportedException();

           public static string JsonQuery(this string column, [NotParameterized] string path) => throw new NotSupportedException();
          }
   ```
2. Include the database functions on your OnModelCreating method.

   ```
           protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
           {
               base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

               modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(
                 typeof(DBF).GetMethod(nameof(DBF.JsonValue))!
               ).HasName("JSON_VALUE").IsBuiltIn();

               modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(
                   typeof(DBF).GetMethod(nameof(DBF.JsonQuery))!
               ).HasName("JSON_QUERY").IsBuiltIn();

               /// ...

               modelBuilder.Entity(entity => {
                   //treat entity as text
                   entity.Property(x => x.Metadata)
                         .HasColumnType("varchar") 
                         .HasMaxLength(8000); 

               });
            }
   ```
3. Call them dynamically with LINQ.

   ```
        var a = await _context.FileInformation
           .AsNoTracking()
           .Where(x => x.Metadata!.JsonValue("$.Property1") == "some value")
           .Select(x => x.Metadata!.JsonValue("$.Property2"))
           .ToListAsync();
   ```

You can add casts or even build anonymous types with this method.

Comment: Brilliant! Now, if I make thin wrapper functions (like creating the "$.X" based on params) over those DBFs will efcore be able to translate them?

Comment: It is possible to use the same way for Datetime or number. Not only string

Comment: but how to be with arrays? how to filter when a nested value inside JSON is an array?

Answer (score 1):

My solution was I added a new class which has `KEY` and `VALUE` , which will represent the dictionary i needed :

```
public class DictionaryObject
{
    public string Key { set; get; }
    public string Value { set; get; }
}
```

and instead of having this line in the JSON class :

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Name { get; set; }
```

I changed to :

```
public List<DictionaryObject> Name { get; set; }
```

Hope it helps.