# Using EF Core to store a object in a json column

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Using the new features of EF Core 7, I am trying to store in a json column a `object`, but I always get a empty json document `{}`.

My class is:

```
 public class TaskActivity
 {

     public int Id { get; set; }
     public DateTime DateUtc { get; set; }
     public int Type { get; set; }
     public object Data { get; set; }

 }
```

In `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TaskActivity>()
    .OwnsOne(x => x.Data, builder => { builder.ToJson(); });
```

Adding the migration, it adds correctly the `Data`  column in the MSSQL table:

`Data = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: true)`

When  I assign a value to `Data` and then add the new entity to the table

`record.Data = new {A=2, B=4};`

I can see how the record is really added, but `Data` contains a empty json doc `{}`.

Which would be the correct way to store a dynamic json in a SQL table?

Comment: Try to use type other than `object` for the `Data` property. The deserializer probably does not know, how to handle the type of the object and deserialize it.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/74896024/5045688